# Bringing rational functions to canonical form

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have a complicated expression, which among other things has stuff like functions of rational functions:

```
expr = f[x/(-x^2 + y)] + f[-(x/(x^2 - y))] (* + ...*)
```

If you apply `Simplify` to the whole expression, they combine, which is what I ultimately want to achieve:

```
Simplify[expr]

(* 2 f[-(x/(x^2 - y))] ... *)
```

However, my complicated expression is so complicated, I prefer not to apply any top-level functions on the entire thing, since it will take a lot of time.

My solution to this problem is to map these top-level functions to the arguments of `f` like so,

```
expr /. f[x_] :> f[Simplify[x]]
```

in the hopes of making the fractions look the same so that they combine.  But it doesn't work.  Is there another way to achieve this task?  (putting these fractions in canonical form, etc.)

Comment: `expr /. f[x_] :> f[Factor[x]]` works for the example provided.

Comment: You could use `Together[]` for this.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thanks, but `Factor` doesn't work for `-(x/(a^2 - x))` and `x/(-a^2 + x)`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, but `Together` doesn't work for `-(x/(a^2 - x))` and `x/(-a^2 + x)`

Comment: In that case, try composing like so: `Together[Apart[(* stuff *)]]`, but this might be more effort-intensive than `Simplify[]` in some cases. BTW: you might be helped by ``Internal`RationalFunctionQ[]``.

Comment: @J.M. ``Internal`RationalFunctionQ[]`` works provided I give it a list of symbols in the second argument to test the expression with.  But I wouldn't know them beforehand.  It would be nice if it would test by using all `Symbols` as variables.

Comment: Then maybe you can do ``Reduce`FreeVariables[expr]`` to get the required symbols.

Comment: You could try to extract the source of Factor2 from FeynCalc, which solves your problem. After loading (any version of) FeynCalc just do `Factor2@{-(x/(a^2 - x)), x/(-a^2 + x)}` and you get `{-(x/(a^2 - x)), -(x/(a^2 - x))}` . I never really understood why Factor does not do this by default. So I coded Factor2.

Comment: @J.M. So here's what I came up with:  ``f[x_?(Internal`RationalFunctionQ[#, Reduce`FreeVariables[#]] &)] :> 
 f[Together@Apart@x]``  Is that what you had in mind.  Quite a lot of undocumented functions there...

Comment: @RolfMertig Yes, I agree it would be nice if a built-in function would do this seemly simple thing.  I just now tried `Apart2` and it seems to do exactly what I need... I'll have a look at the source; thanks!

Comment: Well, I'd have done it as ``f[x_ /; Internal`RationalFunctionQ[x, Reduce`FreeVariables[x]]]``, but that's just my style; you've got it.

Comment: @RolfMertig silly question -- I can't seem to find the file in the FeynCalc that contains the source of `Factor2`.  Would you let me know which file it's in?

Comment: @QuantumDot I think you are looking for the `Factor2.m` file in the "general" folder of the compressed file you get when you download the latest version of FeynCalc.

Comment: @QuantumDot See here: https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/blob/master/FeynCalc/Shared/Factor.m

Comment: This query would benefit from a concrete example, perhaps in an attached nb.